# Can I use Apache 2.0 ErrorDocument and Mod Alias to store error pages outside the DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'd like to store my nicely designed set of http error documents outside the DocumentRoot.

```
Alias /errors /data/opt/apache-httpd-2.0.63/htdocs/errorpages/
<Directory  "/data/opt/apache-httpd-2.0.63/htdocs/errorpages/">
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Directory> 

ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/default.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/default.html
ErrorDocument 502 /errors/default.html
ErrorDocument 503 /errors/default.html
```

However, when I do this, all I get is "The requested URL /errors/default.html resulted in an error."

Is it possible to use mod_alias and the ErrorDocument directive together like this in Apache 2.0?

Comment: Are the files in that directory readable by the webserver user? What does the apache error_log say?

Comment: Visiting /errors/default.html directly works or throws the same error?

Comment: Works. Notably, the docs specify that ErrorDocuments are handled "relative to the DocumentRoot".

Answer (score 2):

I use the following configuration:

```
Alias /error/ /var/www/err/
ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html
```

Just add a "/" to your alias and you should be fine...

Comment: Hum - tried that, and it still doesn't work.

Does there have to be a directory section applied to the alias directory?

Comment: yes, do you got mod_alias loaded?